# Optimization find polynomial coefficients using constraints

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization

I am looking for an optimisations tool for python like pyswarm which tries to find polynomial coefficients by trying different coefficients values. To guide the search I want to add additional constraints eg. the values of the polynomial needs to be between limits or can have a maximum gradient of a certain value. In case that the optimizer chooses coefficients which don't satisfy these constraints, new coefficients need to be chosen instantly instead of using the created polynomial.

Background information:
The polynomial generated by the optimizer will then be used by a different program generating a data set. The generated data will be compared to an existing data set. The goal is to match the data as closely as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Tom, I'm not sure but would a Lagrange polynomial fit the bill?

Comment: Looking at the problem again a Lagrange polynomial would probably work. If I give it random points a curve would be fitted to these points is this correct? Would I be able to get the Y value at each corresponding X value?

Comment: Yes, it'll match the specified points exactly. The only limitation is that for a given value of x you can have only one y. I reread your post and I'm wondering what's the role of the constraints on the values the polynomial assumes? Was this necessary only to perform search? Also, if you could share why you came up with this problem and how you want to use the polynomial then we'd be able to give more specific advice. Thanks.

Comment: I need to create a curve (temperature distribution) which matches a second curve (also temperature distribution). The problem is that the first curve is at 0s while the second curve is at time 60s. With an additional program I can move from the first curve to the second at 60s. So I want to create a random first curve, compute what the curve looks after 60s and compare it with the temperature distribution I have. Then optimise the curve fit between at 60s. Complicated Sorry!!!
I tried Lagrange polynomials and they don't work as I can't achieve the curve needed. Bezier curves might work.